# Relation of totient, cycle length of multiplication and divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I am reading about the dynamics of multiplication $\pmod m$ , and the totient function.
So from what I have understood, the totient function $\phi(n)$ is the cardinality of $\Phi(n)$ which is the set of elements between $1$ and $n - 1$ that are co-prime to $n$.

This totient function is apparently used to define the number of elements of $\Phi(n)$ of cycle-length $\lambda$.
Now I read that if we have a prime number $p$ the possible cycle lengths are the divisors of $p - 1$.
I have verified that as follows:

E.g for $p = 13$ the divisors of $12 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}$
If we multiply by $3 \pmod {13}$ we have a cycle of length $3$ i.e.

```
1 -> 3 -> 9 -> 1
```

Or if we multiply by $5 \pmod {13}$ we have a cycle of length $4$ i.e.

```
1 -> 5 -> 12 -> 8 -> 1
```

I have tried with all the numbers up to $N-1 = 12$ and the cycle lengths are as follows:

| $a^x \pmod {13}$ | $\lambda$ |
| --- | --- |
| $2$ | 12 |
| $3$ | 4 |
| $4$ | 6 |
| $5$ | 4 |
| $6$ | 12 |
| $7$ | 12 |
| $8$ | 4 |
| $9$ | 3 |
| $10$ | 6 |
| $11$ | 12 |
| $12$ | 3 |

Now I can see that indeed all the cycle lengths are divisors of $N - 1$.
I also can see that there are $\phi(12)=4$ primitive roots.

What I can't understand is why are the lengths always divisors of $12$ and how come $\phi(\lambda)$ will indeed show me the number of elements of $\Phi(N)$ with length $\lambda$ but the corresponding $\Phi(\lambda)$ does not contain those elements.

E.g. as mentioned:
$\Phi(12) = {1, 5, 7, 11}$ and indeed we have $4$ elements of $\Phi(13)$ with cycle length $\lambda = 12$ but those are: $2, 6, 7, 11$.

Could someone please help me understand the concepts and intuition here?
Also are the ideas different if $m$ was a composite instead of prime?

**Update:**
So I thought about it a bit, and I came to the following conclusion:
For each $a \in {1..N-1}$ we have a cycle length $\lambda$ and for $N = 13$ we can see in the table above the various lengths.

Now unless $\lambda = N - 1$ which happens only for primitive roots, we have more than $1$ cycle for each number e.g. $c$ to indicate the number of cycles.
Since all the numbers must appear to a cycle, it must be that:
$c \cdot \lambda = N - 1 \implies c \mid (N - 1) \And \lambda \mid (N - 1)$
but this means that the length is always a divisor of $N - 1$.

Assuming I got this part right, it is still not clear to me how the totient can give the proper length even if the contents of the relevant set are completely different

Answer (score 1):

The existence of the primitive root $r$ shows to us that we can think of the elements that are coprime to $p$ as $r,r^2,\dots,r^{p-1} = 1$.

It follows that multiplication between two elements is just the same as adding  the exponents $\bmod p-1$.

So now we just need to consider $\mathbb Z_{p-1}$ under adition and look at the orders, the order of an element $a$ is equal to $\frac{p-1}{gcd(a,p-1)}$ and so the ones with order $p-1$ are the ones that are coprime to $p-1$.

---

If $n$ is not prime then you can still determine the group structure of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_n$ by using the chinese remainder theorem on each prime power factor. It turns out that the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_{p^k}$ is cyclic for odd $p$ and is $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_{2^{k-2}}$ when $p$ is $2$. So by the chinese remainder theorem the group structure is just the direct product of those groups, and you can determine the number of elements of each order using this factorization.

Comment: I think your explanation is about the primitive root. E.g. $r = 2$ is a primitive root in my example, and the cycle includes all the $12$ numbers (i.e. $N - 1$). But I didn't understand how that relates to my questions on the totient and why the $\lambda$ is always a divisor of $N - 1$

Comment: I also didn't understand how we jump to the part `...under adition and look at the orders...`

Comment: Suppose you want to find the order of an element $x\bmod p$. You can write $x$ as $r^a$ where $r$ is the primitive root and $a$ is in the range $0,p-1$. Then the order of $x$ is going to be equal to $\frac{p-1}{\gcd(a,p-1)}$. So that instantly tells us that the orders, or cycle lengths, are divisors of $p-1$.

Comment: Assume you want to count how many elements have order $(p-1)/d$, then this means that the element is of the form $r^{da}$ where $a$ is coprime to $(p-1)/d$, there are $\varphi((p-1)/d)$ options, it follows that there are $\varphi(\lambda)$ elements of order $\lambda$ for every divisor $\lambda$ of $p-1$. I have to do some paperwork but I'll be back in 2 hours if you need anything.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are using the term "order of" and cycle length $\lambda$ interchangeably. I can verify what you wrote in your comment because in my example where $p = 13$ we have e.g. $r = 2$ and if we are interested in the order/cycle length of $5 \mod 13$ we have $5 = 2^9$ and hence $a = 9$ and $\frac{12}{\gcd(9, 12)} = \frac{12}{3} = 4$ and I can see from the table in my post that the length for $5$ is indeed $4$. The problem is that I don't understand anything here. I think you are assuming I know something that I don't

Comment: But basically I just am able to confirm your comments/answers but I don't really understand the concept/intuition behind these

Comment: Could you please see the update in my post?

Comment: I saw the update in the post, I can delete this answer if you would like, maybe that way someone who is better suited to help can answer.

Comment: No, please leave it. I think I'll need to read it multiple times to get most of it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note:

$$x^{2k}=(-x)^{2k}$$

While it may seem at first trivial, it means in mod, that if $x$ has even order, then $-x$ will have at most that order. Noting that : $$x^{2k+1}=-((-x)^{2k+1})$$ and $$(-1)^2=1$$  we see if $-1$ shows up somewhere on either path at any position, the other path has at most twice that length.

To have an order at all ( and not merely a cycle length) , $a$ and $p$ must be coprime, and then $$a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$$  and since $$1\cdot 1=1$$ any two powers returning $1$ as a remainder, can be multiplied or divided ( adding/subtracting their exponents) to form another power that returns $1$ , so if two coprime exponents were to both return $1$ you would end up with a cycle length of $1$ at some point. This is why cycle lengths divide the number of coprimes.

Comment: When you say "even order" do you mean a cycle length that is an even number? If yes, is order and cycle length interchangeable terms?

Comment: Cycle length is broader $2^n$ follows $2,4,8,6,2,... $ modulo $10$ for example. But order, is the least exponent that hit's remainder 1.

Comment: `that if  has even order` does that mean $x^{2n} \equiv 1 \pmod p$?

Comment: `To have an order at all ( and not merely a cycle length)` I don't understand this statement. I thought order means $n$ for which $x^n \equiv 1 \pmod p$. But now I am not sure

Comment: Order has that meaning. Cycles can exist that don't pass through 1 if the base isn't coprime to the modulus though. And yes to your previous comment assuming $2n$ is the least exponent to have that occur.

Comment: `if −1 shows up somewhere on either path at any position, the other path has at most twice that length.` what is the "other path"?

Comment: Example modulo 7,  $3^n$ goes $3,2,6,4,5,1$ now you'll see $6$ aka $-1$ shows up. And $4^n$ aka $(-3)^n$ in modulo 7, goes $4,2,1$ which is because $6$ showed up in an odd position. Had it shown up in an even position then the square of the value ( aka double the exponent, taking twice as many steps) produces $1$ and so you can conclude that the length of both $x^n$ and $(-x)^n$ have order twice where $-1$ shows up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127785/discussion-between-roddy-macphee-and-jim).

Comment: That example in the chat seems interesting, but I dont understand it. If you have time, I'll be checking the chat